# DocuSign SOAP API - Title Tab

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have the following code to add title tab to the DocuSign document - not a template - in C#.

It has worked up until now, but today the tab on the document comes up vertically, so all characters in the title show up vertically.

I am only seeing this when I go to correct the document on DocuSign web site. It does not show that way when I receive for signature. I was not correcting anything, but just checking to ensure that everything  was as expected.

Instead of
Manager
it comes up as 
M
a
n
a
g
e
r

How can I fix that? The code is below.

```
tab13.PageNumber = "17";
tab13.DocumentID = docId;
tab13.Type = DocuSignAPI.TabTypeCode.Custom;
tab13.CustomTabType = DocuSignAPI.CustomTabType.Text;
tab13.Name = "txtTitle";
tab13.Value = mgrTitle;
tab13.CustomTabTypeSpecified = true;
tab13.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
tab13.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = "Title:";
tab13.AnchorTabItem.Unit = DocuSignAPI.UnitTypeCode.Pixels;
tab13.AnchorTabItem.UnitSpecified = false;
tab13.AnchorTabItem.IgnoreIfNotPresent = true;
tab13.AnchorTabItem.UnitSpecified = true;
tab13.AnchorTabItem.YOffset = -20;
tab13.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 50;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: The screenshot is attached in the original text.

Answer (score -1):

I am only seeing this when I go to correct the document on DocuSign web site. It does not show that way when I receive for signature. I was not correcting anything, but just checking to ensure that everything  was as expected.

Comment: Its not an answer to the qs, it should be added as a comment

Comment: It is indeed an answer. It just is a different behavior then in the past.